# Swapping the dimensions of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy, dimensions

I would like to do the following:

```
for i in dimension1:
  for j in dimension2:
    for k in dimension3:
      for l in dimension4:
        B[k,l,i,j] = A[i,j,k,l]
```

without the use of loops. In the end both A and B contain the same information but indexed
differently.

I must point out that the dimension 1,2,3 and 4 can be the same or different. So a numpy.reshape() seems difficult.

Comment: What are the `dimension` variables? Did you miss some `range` calls?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Please note: [Jaime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944468/190597) is better. NumPy provides `np.transpose` precisely for this purpose.

---

Or use [np.einsum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html); this is perhaps a perversion of its intended purpose, but the syntax is quite nice:

```
In [195]: A = np.random.random((2,4,3,5))

In [196]: B = np.einsum('klij->ijkl', A)

In [197]: A.shape
Out[197]: (2, 4, 3, 5)

In [198]: B.shape
Out[198]: (3, 5, 2, 4)

In [199]: import itertools as IT    
In [200]: all(B[k,l,i,j] == A[i,j,k,l] for i,j,k,l in IT.product(*map(range, A.shape)))
Out[200]: True
```

Comment: @DSM - I think you get the "bad pun of the day" award!

Comment: This is the best solution for me as I have in fact 7 dimensions and multiple swap or roll is difficult. I actually though about einsum but somehow used it with the wrong syntax and could not do it. Thanks a lot !!! I love einsum so much <3

Answer (score 138):

The canonical way of doing this in numpy would be to use [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)'s optional permutation argument. In your case, to go from `ijkl` to `klij`, the permutation is `(2, 3, 0, 1)`, e.g.:

```
In [16]: a = np.empty((2, 3, 4, 5))

In [17]: b = np.transpose(a, (2, 3, 0, 1))

In [18]: b.shape
Out[18]: (4, 5, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 16):

You could [`rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis) twice:

```
>>> A = np.random.random((2,4,3,5))
>>> B = np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(A, 2), 3, 1)
>>> A.shape
(2, 4, 3, 5)
>>> B.shape
(3, 5, 2, 4)
>>> from itertools import product
>>> all(B[k,l,i,j] == A[i,j,k,l] for i,j,k,l in product(*map(range, A.shape)))
True
```

or maybe [`swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) twice is easier to follow:

```
>>> A = np.random.random((2,4,3,5))
>>> C = A.swapaxes(0, 2).swapaxes(1,3)
>>> C.shape
(3, 5, 2, 4)
>>> all(C[k,l,i,j] == A[i,j,k,l] for i,j,k,l in product(*map(range, A.shape)))
True
```

Comment: +1 On a side note, `product(*map(range, A.shape))` can be written a bit more cleanly as `np.ndindex(*A.shape)`.

Answer (score 6):

One can also leverage [**`numpy.moveaxis()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) for *moving* the required axes to desired locations. Here is an illustration, stealing the example from [Jaime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944468/2956066):

```
In [160]: a = np.empty((2, 3, 4, 5))

# move the axes that are originally at positions [0, 1] to [2, 3]
In [161]: np.moveaxis(a, [0, 1], [2, 3]).shape 
Out[161]: (4, 5, 2, 3)
```

Comment: can you look at my question here:  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58123/np-shape-1-reversal-of-dims-and-np-moveaxis-splitting-array  How is `np.moveaxis()` splitting the array into r, b, g?  My instructor told me it's `np.split()` but is that implicitly called with `np.movieaxis`?

Answer (score 2):

I would look at numpy.ndarray.shape and itertools.product:

```
import numpy, itertools
A = numpy.ones((10,10,10,10))
B = numpy.zeros((10,10,10,10))

for i, j, k, l in itertools.product(*map(xrange, A.shape)):
    B[k,l,i,j] = A[i,j,k,l]
```

By "without the use of loops" I'm assuming you mean "without the use of nested loops", of course. Unless there's some numpy built-in that does this, I think this is your best bet.

Comment: In NumPy, one of the general goals of avoiding loops is to get the C part of the code to do the heavy lifting. That means nested loops or `itertools.product` are both undesirable.

Comment: Thank you metaperture !
What are you suggesting user2357112 ? Which C routine can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Jaime's answer is correct and np.transpose is the solution. but he did not explain how to calculate **permutation argument**. So, I want to explain how to calculate it correctly here:

If you have a 4 dimensional axis array like: (i, j, k, l), and you want to transpose them into (k, l, i, j), first you must number each axis pythonically, so in given example: "i" is axis=0, "j" is axis =1, "k" is axis=2, and "l" is axis=3. Then you should **maintain** original axis numbers and arrange **those numbers** into final desired axes arrangement, as in: k should be placed in axis=0 and k was represented by number 2 so 2 sits in position of axis=0 which gives => (2, , , )... and by maintaining the same condition for other axes the permutation argument of (2,3,0,1) will be obtained. However, It is easy to mistake *final axis numbers* instead of the original ones in calculating the permutation argument, like mistakenly considering: "i" should become axis=2, "j" should become axis=3, "k" should become axis=0, and "l" should become axis=1, which *surprisingly* gives (2,3,0,1) correctly again but this manner of calculation can give a wrong answer in other cases. For example, if you were to transpose (i, j, k, l) into (i, k, l, j), the first method calculates the permutation argument correctly as (0,2,3,1) but the second method calculates it mistakenly as (0,3,1,2), as it is shown in below:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ones((500,3,512,512))
# Changing A dimensions into (500,512,512,3)
B = np.transpose(A, (0,2,3,1))
C = np.transpose(A, (0,3,1,2))
print(np.shape(B))  # permutation is correct
print(np.shape(C))  # permutation is wrong
```

which prints:

```
size of B is: (500, 512, 512, 3)
size of C is: (500, 512, 3, 512)
```