# How do I reshape array of images obtained from .h5 file in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I apologize in advance if my question seems trivial.

I have a .h5 file containing pairs of images in greyscale organized in match and non-match groups. For my final purpose I need to consider each pair of images as a single image of 2 channels (where each channel is in fact an image).

To use my data I proceed like this:

1. I read the .h5 file putting my data in numpy arrays (I read both groups match and non-match, both with shape (50000,4096)):

   ```
    with h5py.File('supervised_64x64.h5','r') as hf:
        match = hf.get('/match')
        non_match = hf.get('/non-match')
        np_m = np.asarray(match)
        np_nm = np.asarray(non_match)
        hf.close()
   ```
2. Then I try to reshape the arrays:

   ```
   reshaped_data_m = np_m.reshape(250000,2,4096)
   ```

Now, if I reshape the arrays as (250000,2,4096) and then I try to show the corresponding images what I get is actually right. But I need to reshape the arrays as (25000,64,64,2) and when I try to do this I get all black images.

Can you help me? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To know how to help you, you need to provide a little bit more information about the images themselves. What format are they saved in? as a 1D array of 4096 numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that the images are saved in bmp and the arrays are 1D of 4096 float64 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you need to first transpose your input matrix from `250000x2x4096` to `250000x4096x2`, after which you can do the `reshape`.

Luckly, numpy offers the [transpose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) function which should do the trick. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943379/swapping-the-dimensions-of-a-numpy-array) for a bigger discussion around transposing.

In your particular case, the invocation would be:

```
transposed_data_m = numpy.transpose(np_m, [1, 3, 2])
reshaped_data_m = tranposed_data_m.reshape(250000, 64, 64, 2)
```

Comment: nice, I did not even see that the `2` changed places. I think this might be the solution OP is looking for

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately I keep getting black images.