# How to reshape a blob from ( N , C , H , W ) to ( N , H , W ,C )?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, blob, reshape

I have a blob with dimensions ( N, C, H, W) and i want to reshape it into (N, H, W, C). Directly reshaping hasn't been much helpful. Can someone help please??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swapping the dimensions of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23943379/swapping-the-dimensions-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Not sure what [tag:blob] have to do here. You probably have a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Do you just want to reshape or actually 'swapaxes'?

Comment: Yeah, i needed to swap axis only. Also added blob because people who have worked with blob must regularly deal with this. So it could help in future too. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

`transpose` it:

```
In [344]: X = np.ones((2,3,4,5),int)
In [345]: X.transpose(0,2,3,1).shape
Out[345]: (2, 4, 5, 3)
```